# If three equal free masses $M$ are at rest at vertex of equlateral triangle of length $R$ at $t=0$.what is relation between position and time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I need a equation describing relationship between position of particle and time.You can assume only gravitational interaction between masses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton’s second law tells us that the acceleration of a body of mass $m$ experiencing a force $\mathbf{F}$ is given $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{F}/m$.

Given that you are only concerned with the gravitation force, we can calculate it so: $$\mathbf{F}_G = G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$

Given the symmetry of the problem, you may want to consider a 1-D radial coordinate system. You should only have to do the calculation once (as all three masses are experiencing the same thing).

Comment: I need exact answer for verification of my answer @Riley jacob